# How to move more than a partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I wonder if we can move more than one partition at a time.

I mean: Let's say we have a HDD with 3 partitions:

1) An old Windows/DOS partition (with all our data, documents, etc.)

2) The Linux OS partition.

3) The Linux Swap partition.

In that order on the HDD surface.

Now we want to move the Linux OS partition to the first part of the HDD (where the old Windows/DOS partition is), and that old Windows/DOS partition to the rest of the HDD surface.

Of course, the final goal would be to move both partitions at the same time.

Can we do this?

How?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why? Computer does not know difference between partition in one location or another. Some in past discussed rotational speed, but difference is so tiny as best ignored.

Comment: No, you can't. Gparted always does its actions in sequence. Plus moving windows will break it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no tools that let you do this.

Gparted (the de-facto tool to do this in Linux/Ubuntu) will always do its actions in sequence with the official tools for a given file system. After and during every action it will also do checks and rechecks to make certain it all goes as it should go. Even  trivial actions like setting a label are done in sequence.  Gparted FAQ even has a note on Windows:

> **7: Is there a maximum to the amount of operations in the list?**
>
> Nope, that is, not one an ordinary human being will ever reach. I
>   myself tested it with up to 150 operations and it went smoothly.
>
> HOWEVER, I think it's wise to keep the amount of successive operations
>   limited. After all it's your data which is at risk. Especially when
>   doing complex operations (copy,resize) I advise you to take it one
>   step at a time.
>
> **When resizing boot NTFS partitions, it is advisable to perform this as a single operation only. After resizing, boot into Windows twice to allow Windows to perform its checking operations.**